# Como alterar o mês de uma coluna com valores de outra

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, replace

Tenho uma coluna de datas (Mês_fechamento) que gostaria de substituir apenas os meses, usando os valores de uma outra coluna (Clone1).
Esse é o df:

```
      Dat_Avs_Sin  Dat_Fch_Sin Mês_fechamento  Vlr_Cbt_Sin  Fraude  Clone1
92     2018-01-09   1586908800     2020-01-31      5700.00     0.0       4
105    2018-02-11   1592352000     2020-01-31     29947.33     0.0       6
114    2018-03-02   1594166400     2020-01-31      1994.06     0.0       7
115    2018-03-02   1594166400     2020-01-31      6281.09     0.0       7
120    2018-03-27   1586908800     2020-01-31      1099.00     0.0       4
...           ...          ...            ...          ...     ...     ...
40553  2020-12-30   1609286400     2020-01-31     32000.00     0.0      12
40554  2020-12-30   1609286400     2020-01-31      8480.00     0.0      12
40555  2020-12-30   1609286400     2020-01-31     13716.20     0.0      12
40556  2020-12-30   1609372800     2020-01-31      1040.00     0.0      12
40558  2020-12-30   1609286400     2020-01-31      2799.20     0.0      12

[29372 rows x 6 columns]
```

Tentei usar:

```
list = [df['Clone1']]
df['Mês_fechamento']=df['Mês_fechamento'].apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(month=list))
```

Mas retorna erro:
"ValueError: value must be an integer, received <class 'list'> for month"

Tentei também:

```
`list = [df['Clone1']] df['Mês_fechamento']=df['Mês_fechamento'].apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(month=int(float("list"))))`
```

Mas retorna:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'list'
```

Como posso fazer essa operação usando **pandas** ?

Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: Amigo, o erro parece claro - tu deverias usar um int, mas está colocando um list no campo month. Verifica isso...

Comment: Como eu faço para usar um int ? Já tentei passar o nome da coluna mas retorna o mesmo ValueError. Obrigado

Comment: Seria bom colocar uma amostra de quatro linhas **do CSV** usado para gera o DF para testes, também seria bom mostrar como lê o CSV pois influi na manipulação de tempo e datas. Tem um problema com a lógica da pergunta, veja a primeira linha o mês de fechamento é `2020-01-31` possui trinta e um dias, clone é `4` ou o mês de abril que possui trinta dias ou seja se fizer `2020-04-31` irá gerar erro, isso acontece outras vezes. Evite usar apply() é lento. Prefira usar os métodos especializados em datas como nesse [exemplo](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/clone1#main.py) baseado em sua pergunta.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Augusto, você solucionou meu problema ! Em relação a ao erro do dia não bater com o mês, eu usei `df['Mês_fechamento']=pd.to_datetime(df['Mês_fechamento'])  + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd()`  e resolveu. Muito Obrigado de novo.

Answer (score -4):

`list` é um nome reservado para a classe `list`. Tu não pode usar esse nome em uma variável.

No segundo exemplo do teu comentário ao invés de referenciar a variável `list`, tu está tentando transformar a string "list" em um ponto flutuante, que também não é o que tu quer.

Se tu mudar o nome da variável de *list* pra *lista*, por exemplo:

```py
lista = [df['Clone1']]
df['Mês_fechamento'] = df['Mês_fechamento'].apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(month = lista))
```

Isto também não vai funcionar porque tu está tentando usar o método `replace()` do `datetime` com uma lista ao invés de um número inteiro.

O valor do argumento `month` precisa ser um número entre 1 e 12.

---

Umas das soluções possíveis:

```py
import datetime

df['Mês_fechamento'] = [datetime.datetime.strptime(df['Mês_fechamento'][x], '%Y-%m-%d').replace(month = y) for x, y in df['Clone1'].iteritems()]
```

Isto funciona no teu caso porque o índice (x) de cada linha da `Series` `df['Mês_fechamento']` vai usar o valor (y) do mesmo índice da outra `Series` que tu quer usar pra substituir.

Comment: No meu código ele deu o mesmo ValueError, obrigado mesmo assim.

Comment: Porque o replace() do datetime precisa de um número, e tu está mandando uma lista. tu tem que encontrar o valor da lista para cada iteração equivalente

Comment: Tem algum link onde posso encontrar informações de como fazer isso ?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com uma abordagem diferente para atingir o resultado

Comment: Está retornando `NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined` mesmo depois de usar `import`

Comment: ou tu usa `import datetime` e no código usa `datetime.datetime.strptime`, ou então `from datetime import datetime` e no código muda pra `datetime.strptime`